# How does Kubernetes enforce the memory limit for a container?

Tags: kubernetes

How does it enforce the limit? Is it via cgroups? Or is there an actual process watching container processes and terminating them?

I seem to have a container process that gets a SIGKILL, but the pod does not get restarted (but the process dies because SIGKILL). So I'm unsure what the cause of it is.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50632

> IIUC, the process which consumes the most memory will be oom-killed in
>   this case. The container won't terminate unless the killed perocess is
>   the main process within the container.